# Is it posible to get multiple selected files from dialogbox or textbox to FileSystemWatcher instead of just directory?

Tags: dialog, filesystemwatcher

I am selecting multiple files through a dialogbox and showing the complete path with filenames and extensions in TextBox1.text. I am wondering if we can grab the files with complete path and extension to FileSystemWatcher from either DialogBox or from the TextBox. currently, I can just get the directory in FileSystemWatcher.

Thanks.

Code behind DialogBox.

```
private void BTNBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"\Desktop";
            dialog.Title = "Browse old office files";
            dialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls|Word Files(*.doc)|*.doc|PowerPoint Files(*.ppt)|*.ppt";
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";

            dialog.Multiselect = true;

            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            foreach (string file in dialog.FileNames)
            {
                // textBox1.AppendText(Path.GetFileName(file) + Environment.NewLine);
                textBox1.AppendText(file + Environment.NewLine);
            }


            BTNConvert.Enabled = true;
            BTNClear.Enabled = true;

        }
```

Code for FileSystemWatcher

```
private void BTNConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\");
            fsw.Created += (s, a) => {
                if (!a.FullPath.EndsWith(".xls")) { return; }
                var newName = a.FullPath.Remove(a.FullPath.Length - 3) + "xlsx";
                //var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                //var book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(a.FullPath);
                //book.SaveAs(newName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel12);
                //xlApp.Quit();

                //ProgressBar
                backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

                //Create a Workbook instance
                Spire.Xls.Workbook workbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
                //Load an XLS file
                workbook.LoadFromFile(a.FullPath);
                //Convert the file to XLSX format
                workbook.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Converted Files\newfile.xlsx", Spire.Xls.ExcelVersion.Version2016);


                MessageBox.Show("Conversion completed");


            };


            
        }
```